# Tiktok missing x-tt-params from header

Tags: http-headers, httprequest, tiktok

It seems that recently TickTock removed/changed the request header, taking out the "x-tt-params" parameter.
That was found on the request header like this:

```
headers = {
    'Host': 'm.tiktok.com',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:98.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/98.0',
    'Accept': '*/*',
    'Accept-Language': 'n-US,en;q=0.5',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Referer': 'https://www.tiktok.com/',
    'x-tt-params': '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',
    'Origin': 'https://www.tiktok.com',
    'DNT': '1',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'empty',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site':  'same-site',
}
```

Now its not there any more.

Is there any way to get that parameter from another place?

Create a request using curl like this

```
curl -L -X GET 'https://open.tiktokapis.com/v2/user/info/?fields=open_id,union_id,avatar_url' \
-H '{access token}'
```